# PostgreSQL equivalent of MySQL query variables?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Is there a straightforward way to adapt these types of MySQL queries to PostgreSQL:

1. setting variables in MySQL like

   ```
   set @aintconst = -333
   set @arealconst = -9.999
   ```

   [It seems not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query).
2. Assigning variables from SELECT queries and using those variables subsequently in my SQL like:

   ```
    select @pfID := id from platform where bios like '%INTEL%'
    select @clientID := id from client where platformID = @pfID
   ```

I'd be very grateful for pointers, especially on (2).

Comment: You may find PSQL variables are what you're looking for. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213009/2639

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is easy to do inside a PL/pgSQL function (or a [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-do.html) block):

```
create function myfunc() returns void language plpgsql as $$
  declare
    aintconst constant int = -333;
    arealconst constant real = -9.99;
    pfid int;
    clientid int;
  begin

    select id from platform where bios like '%INTEL%' into pfid;

    select id from client where platformID = pfid into clientid;

  end $$;
```

You can also use [GUC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html) variables:

```
--set a session variable
set mycustom.var = 'value';

--use it
select * from mytable where some_column = current_setting('mycustom.var');
```

Or you can use a CTE with a join:

```
with myvars as (
  select
    -333::int as aint,
    -9.99::real as areal
)

select 
  a.*
from mytable a
join myvars on true
where
  a.thing = aint
```

Comment: If you use the GUC method, how do you setup a variable with an enumerated list of numbers?

Answer (score 13):

I use WITH statements:

```
WITH vars as (SELECT -333::double precision as aintconst,-9.999::double precision as arealconst)
UPDATE table SET col1 = (SELECT aintconst FROM vars)
```

and:

```
WITH platformx AS (SELECT id FROM platform WHERE bios like '%INTEL%')
SELECT id FROM client WHERE platformID = (SELECT id FROM platformx)
```

Answer (score 7):

## PSQL Variables

Since at least version 7.1 PostgreSQL's client has provided this functionality with [`psql` variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

```
\set aintconst  -333
\set arealconst -9.999

SELECT :aintconst AS aintconst, :arealconst AS realconst;
 aintconst | realconst 
-----------+-----------
      -333 |    -9.999
(1 row)
```

Essentially what you want is the ability to script SQL. PSQL has a conditionals and variables, and the ability to feed back dynamically generated SQL which makes this job easier. This isn't server-side functionality in the PostgreSQL world, and generally I would do this in a client language (like Node.js or Perl rather than in `psql`).

Comment: need updates. because latest Postgresql allow: `SET LOCAL variable value`

Comment: Those are for configuration parameters -- that's a totally different thing @EugenKonkov

Answer (score 5):

You already answered this yourself: No, there isn't in plain SQL. You can use PL/PgSQL if you want variables, in a function or a `DO` block.

Most of the uses for query variables in MySQL are satisfied by CTEs (`WITH` queries), window functions, etc in PostgreSQL.

---

Well, actually there is, but they're not suitable for general use within queries. You usually access custom GUCs with `SET` and `SHOW`, but you can instead use:

```
regress=> select set_config('a.b', 'c', false);
 set_config 
------------
 c
(1 row)

regress=> select current_setting('a.b');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 c
(1 row)
```

GUCs are expensive and it's a bad idea to use this for general purpose queries, but there's very occasionally a valid use. You can only use settings like `myapp.variable`, too.

Answer (score 1):

For the second example you don't need a variable (neither in MySQL nor in Postgres):

```
select id 
from client 
where platformID in (select id 
                     from platform 
                     where bios like '%INTEL%');
```

Don't be afraid of sub-queries, Postgres' query optimizer is much smarter than MySQL's.

If the above is too slow, rewriting it into an `exists` query is sometimes faster:

```
select c.id 
from client c
where exists  (select 1
               from platform p
               where c.platformID = p.id
                 and bios like '%INTEL%');
```